# navigationview add custom layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-navigationview

How to add a custom item layout dynamically in navigationview? (not ListView or RecyclerView)

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
            menu.add("new tab").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab);
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```